# In Tableau can I calculate a column based on totals of two other columns?

Tags: calculated-columns, tableau-desktop

I'm new to Tableau and new to posting in Stackoverflow so bear with me.

I have a dataset with variables such as `State`, `County`, `Organization`, `2020 Enrollment`, `2021 Enrollment`, and `Delta` (change in enrollment over those two years). What I want is a column that gives the **percent** delta in enrollment over these two years.

The first thing I tried was calculating a column just using the growth formula:

```
(ZN([2021Enrolled])-ZN([2020Enrolled]))/ZN([2020Enrolled])
```

In the Data View this works great, because nothing is being summed, I get the correct delta. But when I use this formula in my worksheet, what happens is that the formula is being calculated across all the observations (there are several observations per county, per organization, for example) and then summed up. This gives an incorrect delta for year over year.

What I am looking for is a way to calculate the % delta column based on the **total** enrollments for 2020 and 2021 in order to achieve the correct % delta.

I included two screenshots below showing what Tableau is giving, and then an Excel spreadsheet of the same data filtered on just one county to show the problem a little better.

Maybe a similar question has been asked before, but I was unsure just how to search this up. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Sam

[Tableau view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT37I.png)

[Excel view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcBcC.png)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer: I was trying to create a calculated column in Data View, what I needed to do was create a calculated column in my worksheet view, so that it would only work on the data presented there.